# HTML Select, force direction down

Tags: html, select

Is there a way to force the dropdown direction of a select element in HTML down?

At the moment we have a product display page, the select box appears below the halfway mark of the screen in a widescreen resolution and therefore makes the dropdown go up.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, this can't be done with a standard `select` element.

You would have to use a JavaScript based alternative.

A cursory search doesn't reveal any jQuery/JS based alternatives that explicitly offer setting the direction as an option, but I'm sure there is one out there that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so, its up to the browser/OS how it does it.